# How to prevent pages from automatically adding line breaks?

Tags: html, line-breaks

I'm trying to style a form on a website, but I'm hitting a snag. Wordpress is automatically generating `<br>` tags when I directly edit the HTML for pages.

What I've got is this:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>* Your name:</legend>
<ul class="singleLine">
    <li>
    <span>
        <input id="FName" type="text" name="FName" size="20" maxlength="20" />
        <label for="FName">First</label>
    </span>
    <span>
        <input id="LName" type="text" name="LName" size="30" maxlength="40" />
        <label for="LName">Last</label>
    </span>
    </li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
```

...all mashed together into a single line because WP wants to generate `<br>` tags all over the place if I don't. I can deal with that, but I'm actually still getting `<br>` tags generated directly after each`<span>` tag in the resulting page even with all of the HTML smooshed together on one line. How do I get rid of those?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's the portion of the layout that generates the page content.

```
<div id="main-content">
    <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
        <h1 id="pagetitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="pagecontent">
            <?php get_the_content() ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile ?>   
</div>
```

replacing `get_the_content()` with `the_content()` renders properly.

Comment: Wait: you have form field HTML tags *directly in the page content*? How are you doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `get_the_content();` in your page template loop instead of `the_content();`

**EDIT 05/24/2012 - Try this:**

```
<div id="main-content">
    <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
        <h1 id="pagetitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="pagecontent">
            <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile ?>   
</div>
```

P.S. You will also need to consider the rest of your more "normal" wordpress pages through out your site.

You don't want ALL of your pages functioning like that. I would create a page template for the pagess that need to function this way, the rest of your pages should use the normal page.php template.

[Learn more on page templates.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)

Comment: using `get_the_content();` doesn't render anything at all... the div I placed my content in is simply blank when I use that function. Any other ideas/fixes for that? Thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminKovach please update your question with the code for your page template, or more specifically the loop within your page template, before I can be of further assistance.

Comment: @BenjaminKovach provided an update to my solution.